# Result appended twice to table ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, append, laravel-5.8

I am tring to append data to a table. But one of my result is repeating twice. Below is my json response I got.

```
groupname   […]
 0  {…}
 survey_id  2
 group_name DEMO
 1  {…}
 survey_id  1
 group_name TEST
```

My ajax success is as follows

```
if(data){

    var txt = "";
    for(var i=0;i<=Object.keys(data).length;i++){
    if(data ){
      txt += '<tr><td>'+data.groupname[i].group_name+'</td></tr>';
             }
    if(txt != ""){
            $("#table").append(txt);
                 }

            }
       }
```

But it displays as below

[image: img]

I need only 1 DEMO and 1 TEST

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**txt+** will append the previous value also. check if ***data.groupname[I].group_name*** is not empty, then appended the row in table.

```
if(data){
    var txt = "";
    for(var i=0;i<=Object.keys(data).length;i++){
    //txt+ also will append the previous val. SO check if data.groupname[i].group_name is not empty then append.
    if(data.groupname[i].group_name ){
        txt = '<tr><td>'+data.groupname[i].group_name+'</td></tr>';
        $("#table").append(txt);
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain your answer? (and properly indent it?)

Comment: I added in comments,

Comment: Your analysis is correct, but the answer is missing an explanation (a comment in the code cannot be an explanation). Please also indent the code correctly.

Comment: Your point is absolutely correct. It worked... :) Thanks :) will accept this in 2 mins. :)

Comment: @KIKO Software, I added the details with ans. thank you

Comment: Thanks, it is an improvement. We have to think about all the other users that will read this question and answer in the years to come.

Answer (score 0):

you have to append after the for loop, the problem was you collect txt and append in each index of the loop, then the solution collect all rows and then append.

```
if(data){
    var txt = "";
    for(var i=0;i<=Object.keys(data).length;i++){
      if(data ){
        txt += '<tr><td>'+data.groupname[i].group_name+'</td></tr>';
      }
    }
    if(txt != ""){
      $("#table").append(txt);
    }
 }
```